# Jquery "scroll to bottom" only fires at second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Jquery script to make a scroll to bottom button, problem is it only works on the second click. I saw some other topics about it but none of their solutions worked.

I mostly tried:

- adding `$(document).ready(function()` around my code
- setting href void to 0
- adding `return false` at end of `click()`

What I want to use is the prev / previous button

```js
 $(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.totopscroller = function(options) {

   var defaults = {
    showToBottom: true,
    showToPrev: true,
    link: false,
    linkTarget: '_self',
    toTopHtml: '<a href="#"></a>',
    toBottomHtml: '<a href="#"></a>',
    toPrevHtml: '<a href="#"></a>',
    linkHtml: '<a href="#"></a>',
    toTopClass: 'totopscroller-top',
    toBottomClass: 'totopscroller-bottom',
    toPrevClass: 'totopscroller-prev',
    linkClass: 'totopscroller-lnk',
         };

   var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

   var lastposition = 0;
   
   var wrapper = this,
             b_top = null,
             b_bottom = null,
             b_prev = null,
    b_link = null,
    b_wrapper = null;
    
   var init = function() {
    b_wrapper = $('<div></div>');
    if (settings.showToBottom)
    {
     b_bottom = $(settings.toBottomHtml);
     b_bottom.hide();
     b_bottom.addClass(settings.toBottomClass);
     b_bottom.appendTo(b_wrapper);
    }
    if (settings.showToPrev)
    {
     b_prev = $(settings.toPrevHtml);
     b_prev.hide();
     b_prev.addClass(settings.toPrevClass);
     b_prev.appendTo(b_wrapper);
    }
    b_top = $(settings.toTopHtml);
    b_top.hide();
    b_top.addClass(settings.toTopClass);
    b_top.appendTo(wrapper);
    if (settings.link)
    {
     b_link = $(settings.linkHtml);
     b_link.attr("target", settings.linkTarget);
     b_link.attr("href", settings.link);
     b_link.addClass(settings.linkClass);
     b_link.appendTo(wrapper);
    }
    b_wrapper.appendTo(wrapper);
    
    b_top.click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     lastposition = $(document).scrollTop();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 
     {
      duration: 'slow', 
      complete: function () {
       refresh();
      }
     });
    });
    if (settings.showToBottom)
    {
     b_bottom.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      lastposition = 0
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 
      {
       duration: 'slow', 
       complete: function () {
        refresh();
       }
      });
     });
    }
    if (settings.showToPrev)
    {
     b_prev.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:lastposition}, 
      {
       duration: 'slow', 
       complete: function () {
        lastposition = $(document).height() - $(window).height()
        refresh();
       }
      });
     });
    }
   }
   var refresh = function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
     if (!b_top.is(":visible"))
      b_top.fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else if (b_top.is(":visible"))
     b_top.fadeOut("slow");

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() || lastposition > 0) {
     if (b_bottom.is(":visible"))
      b_bottom.fadeOut("slow");
    }
    else if (!b_bottom.is(":visible"))
      b_bottom.fadeIn("slow");

    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 20)
    {
     if (!b_prev.is(":visible"))
      b_prev.fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else if (b_prev.is(":visible"))
      b_prev.fadeOut("slow");
   }

   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('html, body').is(":animated"))
     return;
    refresh();

   });

   init();
   refresh();
   return this;
  };
 }( jQuery ));
```

```css
#totopscroller {
position: fixed;
right: 30px;
bottom: 30px;
width: 43px;
}
#totopscroller div {
width: 49px;
height: 43px;
position: relative;
}
#totopscroller a {
display: none;
background: url('totopicons.png');
width: 49px;
height: 43px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
border: medium none;
margin: 0 0 -1px;
}
.totopscroller-top {
background-position: 0 0 !important;
}
.totopscroller-lnk {
background-position: 0 -43px !important;
}
.totopscroller-prev {
background-position: 0 -129px !important;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.totopscroller-bottom {
background-position: 0 -86px !important;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="display: none;" class="totopscroller-top"></a><div><a href="#" style="display: none;" class="totopscroller-bottom"></a><a href="#" style="display: block;" class="totopscroller-prev"></a></div>
```

Thanks for any advices you might have

Comment: You already have `$(document).ready()` around your code. `$(function($) ...)` is a shortcut for that.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the info

Comment: Do the other buttons work correctly?

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS that goes with this? I can't seem to get the buttons to show when I try to use your code.

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make the example code executable.

Comment: Yes other buttons works correctly, and it's a "a href", not  a "button", I am going to add html and css

Comment: I know it's actually an anchor, but it's acting like a button. You even write "scroll to bottom button".

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the logic in `refresh()` that decides which buttons to show and hide.

Comment: Or maybe it's because of `lastposition = 0;`.

Comment: I cant manage to make it runnable in the snippet but you can check it at www.raphaelchillio.com

Comment: I'm getting an error in the console: `$ is not a function`.

Comment: What would that mean? I am new to debugging

Comment: Change the script to use `jQuery(function($) ...)` instead of `$(function($) ...)`, because something else (maybe something in WordPress?) is undefining `$`. But this doesn't seem to be related to the problem, because the code is running anyway.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the button is initially the Previous button, not the Bottom button.

Comment: I got it ! You was right it was about `lastposition = 0;`

Comment: I changed it to `position = $(document).height` and it works, I think it is because `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:lastposition}` is before `lastposition = $(document).height() - $(window).height()` so it would first go to 0 px then set lastposition to bottom of the page. This was my first post on Stack Overflow so thank you very much @Barmar for your time and advices

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and explain why this fixes it. I don't really understand the logic enough to write an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

changing `lastposition = 0` to `lastposition = $(document).height` was the solution.

The problem was that it was set to 0, and then set to the right value after clicking, causing first clic to get me at the top of the page (no scroll) and second to be effective.